# Execute a cloud function locally

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am following the Node.js  tutorial at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/local-development-with-cloud-functions#3.

My code file is index.js and `main` in package.json is "index.js".

When I execute `node node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework --target=validateTemperature` as per the instructions, nothing happens. It simply returns immediately, with no terminal output or any error messages.

I tried putting some syntactically wrong stuff in index.js, but still no error was triggered.

I am at a loss of how to troubleshoot or proceed. Looking for some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried  following  the steps in the codelabs that you shared and it works fine for me.

instead of running `node node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework --target=validateTemperature` try running `npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=validateTemperature`

Sample Output:

```
$ npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target=validateTemperature

Serving function...
Function: validateTemperature
Signature type: http
URL: http://localhost:8080/
```

You can also check this [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs)

Comment: Yes, using `npx` works, but I wonder why it won't run with simply `node`.

Comment: seems to be documentation error see in this [release notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/functions-framework) also mentioned `npx` command or else /node_modules is missing some packages use of `npx` is it will install and run it without having that package globally installed.

Comment: I got to work with `npm start`, where `start` in package.json is `functions-framework target=validateTemperature`.